# SQLite database scheme as Entity Relationship Model

Tags: database, sqlite, entity-relationship

Is there a tool to display the database scheme for SQLite 3 database like with MySQL Workbench and Reverse Engineering? I mean a graphical representation like [image: Database scheme]

Comment: https://www.dbschema.com/sqlite-designer-tool.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/), it works for any database and I particularly like the way it arranges large diagrams. Check the Personal evaluation license.

Comment: In the tab references I can see the diagram. Do you know how I can display all fields and also 1:1 and 1:n relationship directly on the graphs?

Comment: OK, you have to switch `Node Content` to Columns and activate `Show One Link/Column`. Can I show the type of relationship (1:1, 1:n, ...)?